# construction and destruction of parameterized constructor argument?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17

Here, i am getting different out on different compiler, why is that ?
On msvc compiler, there i'm getting extra destructor statement ?

Why i'm getting this behaviour ?
Am i missing something ?

i had looked many question on stackoverflow, but i can't find anything related to my problem ?

i also tried to look for duplicate, but didn't find one.

```
class A {
public:
    A() 
    {
        std::cout << "A::constructor" << "\n";
    }

    ~A() 
    {
        std::cout << "A::Destructor" << "\n";
    }

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
};
```

```
class B {
public: 

A   member_var_1;
int member_var_2;

    B()
    {
        std::cout << "B::constructor" << '\n';
    }

    B(A a, int b)
    {
        member_var_1 = a;
        member_var_2 = b;
        std::cout << "B(A, int)::constructor " << '\n';
    }

    ~B() 
    {
        std::cout << "B::destructor" << '\n';
    }

};
```

```
int main()
{
    B v1 {A(), 5};
}
```

[GCC output:](https://godbolt.org/z/K3c9f1434)

```
A::consturctor         // parameterized constructor first argument constructor 
A::consturctor         // construction of B's class member (member_var_1)
B(A, int)::consturcotr // B class parameterized constructor
A::Destructor          // Destruction of argument of parameterized constructor
B::destructor          // object goes out of scope, so B destructor called
A::Destructor          // B's Destructor called member's destructor
```

[MSVC output:](https://godbolt.org/z/rjsar9fxz)

```
A::consturctor
A::consturctor
B(A, int)::consturcotr 
A::Destructor
A::Destructor         // what is it destroying? if i define a "class A" copy constructor, then i don't get this output. 
B::destructor
A::Destructor
```

Comment: Probably something related to whether or not `A` counts as an aggregate

Comment: @NathanPierson AFAIK, an aggregate cannot have a user-declared constructor.

Comment: @NathanPierson if you provide "class A " paratermized contructor, you will also get that extra destroying statement and intitailize that B's member (member_var_1). [see](https://godbolt.org/z/cqbWME53e)

Comment: I don't have time to write a complete answer now, but I think that the problem is related to "copy elision" (deferred temporary materialization since C++17). When it does not apply, the `A()` temporary in `B v1 {A(), 5};` is constructed first and then copied/moved into the constructor argument `a`. If copy elision does apply, then `a` is constructed directly by the default constructor. Some live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oz34hrfPr.

Comment: Good point. I was messing with godbolt and noticed that writing `A(const A&) = default;` didn't elide the additional `A` but writing `A(const A&) { }` did. Thought there was some sort of "user-declared/user-provided" distinction but of course `A` already has a user-provided constructor to begin with. Wrong track entirely.

Comment: @DanielLangr From C++17 due to mandatory copy elision there should not be an extra destructor call. But MSVC still gives the extra destructor call output with C++17. Note that gcc and clang does not give extra destructor call output with C++17(due to mandatory copy elision) as expected. A msvc bug perhaps? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n6Yad75WK).

Comment: @DanielLangr if "copy elision" happens, then shouldn't it will call A's copy constructor, but i didn't, perhaps if we explicitly provide a copy constructor that extra destructor statement disappear. Some live demo : [https://godbolt.org/z/bKKcr651h](https://godbolt.org/z/bKKcr651h)

Comment: Here is a **msvc bug report** [MSVC produces extra destructor call even with mandatory copy elision in C++17](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-produces-extra-destructor-call-even/10152483).

Comment: @DanielLangr Note also that OP is using C++17 and not C++11 unlike your given demo. This seems to be a [msvc bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-produces-extra-destructor-call-even/10152483) as msvc still produces the extra destructor call even with c++17's mandatory copy elision.

Comment: @mn_op Yes, I referred to the problem in general. I also believe it's a MSVC bug, as pointed out by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using C++17 and there is **mandatory copy elision** from C++17(&onwards), the extra destructor call must not be there.

A msvc bug has been reported as:

[MSVC produces extra destructor call even with mandatory copy elision in C++17](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-produces-extra-destructor-call-even/10152483)

---

Note that if you were to use C++11 or C++14, then it was possible to get an extra destructor call because prior to c++17 there was no mandatory copy elision and the parameter `a` could've been created using the copy/move constructor which means that you'll get the fourth destructor call as expected. You can confirm this by using the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag with other compilers. See [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/41aqMc1dh) that has a contrived example of this.

Comment: however adding a copy constructor make that statement disappear,  how ? See demo : [https://godbolt.org/z/1Wx4coTY8](https://godbolt.org/z/1Wx4coTY8)

Comment: @mn_op As it is a msvc bug, they'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
B v1 {A(), 5};
```

In MSCV compiler, first, the construction of  temporary A() is happening then it is elided to to "a" argument of parameterized constructor. that's why the extra destruction is happening for this temporary but it shouldn't be here because it is done implicitly.
So it is a bug in MSCV.